# Formatting data output to get numeric variables to always show 2 decmial places

Tags: r

I am running the following code to summarise a variable in r

```
setDT(RWA_Cleansed_Data)[, .(value=sum(ACCOUNT_BALANCE), freq = .N) , by = PERIOD ]
```

The output is

```
   PERIOD        value  freq
1: 201907 167050951793 48840
```

How can I get the value to print with 2 decimal places

I am trying to get R to always show numeric variables with 2 decimal places in the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `formatC`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(RWA_Cleansed_Data)[, .(value=formatC(sum(ACCOUNT_BALANCE),
         digits = 2, format = "f"), freq = .N) , by = PERIOD]
```

Consider a reproducble example with `mtcars`

```
df <- mtcars
setDT(df)[, .(value= formatC(sum(am),digits = 2,format = "f"), freq = .N),by = cyl]

#   cyl value freq
#1:   6  3.00    7
#2:   4  8.00   11
#3:   8  2.00   14
```

This will print `value` with 2 decimal places however, note that `value` column is of class "character" now and needs to be converted to numeric before any further processing.